# Understanding lemma of initial segment

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Lemma. An initial segment of a well-ordered set $\emptyset \neq X$ is either $X$ or of the form $\left( -\infty ,a\right)$ for some a $\in$ $X$.

My question is that why did we write the form $\left( -\infty ,a\right)$, why did not we write the form $(a,\infty)$?

Comment: Every initial segment has to contain $\min(X)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you want *initial* segments, not *final* segments. For example, suppose that $X=\Bbb N$ and $a=3$. Then $(-\infty,3)=\{0,1,2\}$, which is indeed an initial segment of $\Bbb N$, while

$$(3,\infty)=\{4,5,6,\ldots\}$$

is definitely not an initial segment.